# How to attach function that uses `this` to instance-object

Tags: javascript, testing, this

I'm trying to modify and instance-object's behaviour for testing. If you need to know *exactly* what I'm trying to achive, it's this:

```js
const fakeWebSocket$$: WebSocketSubject<any> = new Subject<any>() as WebSocketSubject<any>;
fakeWebSocket$$.multiplex = (x: any, y: any, filterFn: (z: any) => boolean) => 
    fakeWebSocket$$.pipe(filter(filterFn));
```

which is attaching a fake `multiplex`-method to an RxJS-`Subject` to be able to emulate a `WebSocketSubject`.

This works fine, but notice how I have to refer to the `fakeWebSocket$$` twice:

```js
// simplified for readability
fakeWebSocket$$.multiplex = (x, y, filterFn) => fakeWebSocket$$.pipe(filter(filterFn));
```

I'd hope there is a way to replace the second explicit call to `fakeWebSocket$$` with `this`, somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use `this`, you have to rewrite the arrow function to a normal `function` function:

```
fakeWebSocket$$.multiplex = function (x, y, filterFn) {
  return this.pipe(filter(filterFn));
};
```

This usage is not documented, but it should work.

[The documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/WebSocketSubject#multiplex-) however is written in such a way that suggests creating a derived class to override `multiplex()`, rather than assigning a new value directly to the instance:

```
class FakeSubject<T> extends WebSocketSubject<T> {
  override multiplex(
    subMsg: () => any,
    unsubMsg: () => any,
    messageFilter: (value: T) => boolean
  ) {
    return this.pipe(filter(messageFilter));
  }
}

const fakeWebSocket$$ = new FakeSubject();
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, the first solution works perfectly. Learned something new about `this`. However, I don't think the second solution is applicable in this case, since I'm not in fact altering the behaviour of a `WebSocketSubject`. Instead I'm just plugging in an extended `Subject` which I can `next()` from inside the test. I just tell TypeScript to treat it as a `WebSocketSubject`. I could of course use the extend Syntax to add the `multiplex` method there, but that would be very verbose...